# Recursing Error during Periodic Sched function

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, scheduled-tasks

I am running some tests for a function I need to write where I have two separate timed functions happening in a variable amount of time for each execution. These functions would have to be nonblocking.

The test I've created is the following:

```
import sched, time
import threading

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s2 = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def do_something(sc):
    print("doing stuff.")
    sc.enter(5, 1, do_something, (sc,))
    sc.run()

def do_something_else(sc):
    print("doing other stuff.")
    sc.enter(3, 1, do_something_else, (sc,))
    sc.run()

x = threading.Thread(target=do_something, args=(s,), daemon=True)
x.start()
y = threading.Thread(target=do_something_else, args=(s,), daemon=True)
y.start()


while 1:
    pass
```

This test yielded the results I was looking for.
On each call of each method, I can update the amount of delay on the next function call.

The program I am planning to use this on would use this method and leave the loop running for up to hours at a time. I've let this code run for a while to see if it was capable of this. About 10-15 minutes in I encountered this exception:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I'm new to python, coming from JS and Java but is this error similar to stackoverflow? **Is this error preventing me from using all of my memory and crashing the application?** I saw that using the system module the depth can be changed.

From what I understand, the sched I created should terminate and destroy after the next sched is started meaning that memory can't pile up? **If i changed the recursion limit would it allow me to run my program for the desired amount of time without memory crash? Or does this error directly imply that I am on route to a memory crash?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sched.scheduler exceeds max recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404580/python-sched-scheduler-exceeds-max-recursion-depth)

Comment: @quamrana i have just refactored the code in the suggestion to work for my condition. I will update the thread once it has run for some time and I can be sure it will not cause the same error. This suggestion doesn't seem to address why it would solve the recursion issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python sets a standard recursion limit of 1000 iterations. But you can modify this using the [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) library.
You can check the recursion limit using `sys.getrecursionlimit()`
, and you are able to change the recursion limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.

For example, if you want to change the recursion limit to 2000, then you can run `sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`.

However, if you set your recursion limit too high, and your code keeps on iterating, you could get a `memory error` and your program would crash.